# FindViewByID returns null for CustomView

Tags: android, null

I am having trouble with findViewById again in android.
My Activity never exits the while loop, because the listview is always null. I already tried rebuilding. I know about the onFinishedInflating method for views, but it doesn't help me in my Activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.list_with_compass);

    ListWithCompassView lv = (ListWithCompassView) this.findViewById(R.id.compass_list);

    while(lv == null) {
        Log.d("waiting", "waiting1");
        lv = (ListWithCompassView) this.findViewById(R.id.compass_list);
    }
    this.setListView();
}
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear_layout_compass" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <karsunke.view.ListWithCompassView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/compass_list">
    </karsunke.view.ListWithCompassView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is your ListWithCompassView code...???

Comment: It doesn't matter it's just a custom view which extends the View class.

Comment: Have you tried using the hierarchy viewer? You should check whether your custom view is in the hierarchy, and whether it has an identifier assigned to it. I had the same problem as you recently.

Comment: Thank you fleetway76. That was the solution. The way Android inflates the XML-Files is still a little bit confusing to me ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this constructor to your custom view class..

```
public ListWithCompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
```

Comment: I added the constructor, but for some reason I only called the super(context). Because of this the object did not got an ID.

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure if I would have found this. Something so easy to overlook.

Comment: In my custom view's constructor, I previously called super(context) only, without the attribute set. Everything worked fine until I needed to grab the view by using findViewById.

Comment: @FranziskusKarsunke: your "comment" here was the correct answer for me :)

Comment: this solved my problem, but any good explanation for why this is needed?

Comment: @Deep: This is to set the id property used by findViewById(int _id) as the id is set as one of the attributes on the View base class from the layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shoot but try cleaning your project and rebuilding it. Sometimes I received null in findviewbyid for no reason until i rebuilt my project. If that doen't help post the custom class so we can see if the problem is there.